# How to provide access to users per branch level in Multibranch pipeline project?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

In Jenkins, we have some multibranch pipeline projects with three branches Develop, Master and SIT. we have around 10 developers. For 5 developers, i should provide access to just develop branch to run. Also, i should restrict them to run master and SIT branch. can we do this? I tried using matrix based type but its not working  out to provide access per branch level. Thanks for your help and comments...!

Comment: AFAIK, user level restriction per is not possible in multibranch pipeline, reason is all the configuration and settings needs to be done from Jenkinsfile with scripts. Ultimately these will have access to the developers and can change accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Try using project based Matrix Authorization strategy under Configure Global Security.

Comment: Thanks @Anudeep... yes this is what we have in Jenkins. But I can't able to provide access per branch level.